# Duplicate column to generate unique IDs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of ID's in column A

```
10001
10002
10003
10001
10005
10002
10005
… and a lot more.
```

There

```
10001
10002
10005
```

are duplicates.

What I want is code in my excel to read column A and if a duplicate is found it should attach something like '-1' to the duplicate ID so we have something like

```
10001-1
10001-2
10002-1
10002-2
10005-1
10005-2
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formula in B2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,A2 & "-" & COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2),A2)
```

and copy it down.

[image]